# How to implement push notification and file upload and download with webview?

Tags: file-upload, webview, push-notification, download

I was wanting to know how my app can alert users that they have a notification on my forum? Also I'd like to know how I can allow users to upload and download files to and from my forum within the app. I'm using webview and not sure if my code is up to date. I'm a noob when it comes to this stuff.

Here's my code:

```
package technologx.technologx;

/**
 * Created by Technologx on 12/22/15
 * ©2015 Technologx All Rights Reserved
 * http://technologx.fulba.com
 */

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // If the Android version is lower than Jellybean, use this call to hide
        // the status bar.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }

        // Adds Progress Bar Support
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        // Makes Progress Bar Visible
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);

        // Use forum.xml as webview layout
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Adds Zoom Control (You may not need this)
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

        // Enables Multi-Touch. if supported by ROM
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        // Change to your own forum url
        webView.loadUrl("http://technologx.96.lt/");

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // Loads only your forum domain and no others!
                if (url.contains("technologx.96.lt") == true) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    // Adds Progress Bar Support
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, null);
                    findViewById(R.id.progressbar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    // If they are not your domain, use browser instead
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // Removes Progress Bar
                findViewById(R.id.progressbar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // Adds Cookies. Yummy!
                CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
            }
        });
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Enables going back history
        if (webView.copyBackForwardList().getCurrentIndex() > 0) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            // Your exit alert code, or alternatively line below to finish
            // Finishes forum activity
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://technologx.technologx/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://technologx.technologx/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```